# Struct definition contains a static instance of itself?

Tags: c++, syntax, struct

What does it mean when the definition of a struct contains a static instance of itself?

```
struct Quaternion
{
    float q[4];
    static Quaternion IDENTITY;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that this code is C++ and not C.

The static member has a static lifetime and is "shared" between instances of Quaternion (i.e. it isn't a part of any of them).

Comment: In this case it is intended to be the identity quaternion (0,0,0,1).